# Reduce Connecting time to server for inital request

Tags: nginx, performance, page-speed

I am struggling with decreasing load time of inital html page request. It is consistently above 800 ms however other websites they load in less than 300 ms. In this load time GTMetrix shows more than 60% time in connecting only. I don't know why it is so high for my website while for other websites this connecting time is less than 80ms

To access latest report you can see https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.winni.in/wbED7JPf

[image]

What could be the possible ways by which I can further speed up the website? And most importantly the first page should load very fast. I am using nginx as proxy for tomcat on EC2 (AWS Singapore)

Comment: Not a lot we can do from this page. May I assume that your server is vastly too slow or your server configuration was done not properly? On top, that may not be a ngix issue - it could well be the tomcat "forwarding" that takes time. This is all invisible from that nice webpage you show us - and that is where proper system administration starts.

Comment: Is there any tool or way by which I can check whether my server is slow or wrongly configured

Comment: Yes. That depends on your server. But I just realize - you test from CANADA? To Singapore? That alone is a large latency - and I think you need quite some round trips to establish the HTTP connection.